# Compare 2 columns in 2 tables with DISTINCT value

Tags: sql

I am now creating a reporting service with visual business intelligent.

i try to count how many users have been created under an org_id.

but the report consist of multiple org_id. and i have difficulties on counting how many has been created under that particular org_id.

```
TBL_USER

USER_ID

0001122
0001234 
ABC9999         
DEF4545
DEF7676

TBL_ORG

ORG_ID

000
ABC
DEF
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
TBL_RESULT

USER_CREATED

000 - 2
ABC - 1
DEF - 2
```

in my understanding, i need nested `SELECT`, but so far i have come to nothing.

```
SELECT COUNT(TBL_USER.USER_ID) AS Expr1
FROM TBL_USER INNER JOIN TBL_ORG 
WHERE TBL_USER.USER_ID LIKE 'TBL_ORG.ORG_ID%')
```

this is totally wrong. but i hope it might give us clue.

Comment: Please do not SHOUT your questions here. Typing in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read, it's annoying, and it won't get you help any faster. The Shift key is on your keyboard because using upper and lower case letters is much more easier to read. Please use it. Thanks. :-)

Comment: thanks ken. but as u can see. i use my wordings with small case only to differentiate the TABLE entities with upper case in hope it will help others to identify which is my question, and which is my data. sorry if its annoys u. mean no harm. :) @KenWhite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *looks* like the `USER_ID` value is the concatenation of your `ORG_ID` and *something to make it unique*. I'm assuming this is from a COTS product and nothing a human would have built.

Your desire is to find out how many entries there are by department. In SQL, when you read the word `by` in a requirement, that implies grouping. The action you want to take is to get a count and the reserved word for that is `COUNT`. Unless you need something out of the TBL_ORG, I see no need to join to it

```
SELECT
    LEFT(T.USER_ID, 3) AS USER_CREATED
,   COUNT(1) AS GroupCount
FROM
    TBL_USER AS T
GROUP BY
    LEFT(T.USER_ID, 3)
```

Anything that isn't in an aggregate (COUNT, SUM, AVG, etc) *must* be in your GROUP BY.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/11b2c/1)

I updated the fiddle to also show how you could link to TBL_ORG if you need an element from the row in that table.

```
-- Need to have the friendly name for an org
-- Now we need to do the join
SELECT
    LEFT(T.USER_ID, 3) AS USER_CREATED
,   O.SOMETHING_ELSE
,   COUNT(1) AS GroupCount
FROM
    TBL_USER AS T
    -- inner join assumes there will always be a match
    INNER JOIN
        TBL_ORG AS O
        -- Using a function on a column is a performance killer
        ON O.ORG_ID = LEFT(T.USER_ID, 3)
GROUP BY
    LEFT(T.USER_ID, 3)
,   O.SOMETHING_ELSE;
```

Comment: yes. i am trying with GROUP BY. but it is confusing me as im not expert in SQL. but oh wow. that really did the trick. it really group by the amount user created under that particular org.

Comment: it does helped me grouping the user_id. but i still couldnt find the way to select the value to their particular org_id. i need someone to brainstorm the query. but all my officemates is lack of sql knowledge.

Comment: If you find answers helpful, feel free to click the Up arrow. If this solves your problem, you may click the green check mark